# How to write a regex that captures where Upper Case ends and Title Case begins?

Tags: regex

I have tried both getting the all caps:

```
[A-Z/:/s/~]*(^[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+) (^ to show not)
[A-Z/:/s/~]*(?![A-Z]{1}[a-z]+)
```

Or grabbing the sentence case:

```
[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+ 

[A-Z/:/s/~]*(^[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+) (^ to show not)
```

Example:

```
ELIMINATE:TWOS WORD AT THE END OF THIS BUT IGNORE~JUNK~ HELLOTwo Word
```

How can I get "Two word" out of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preferred choice was already given so here is a different one using just the + lookahead.

```
[A-Z](?=[a-z])\w+
```

Regex:

[image: regex]

*[Try it](https://regex101.com/r/GcL8Jg/1)*

Answer (score 2):

`(?<=[A-Z])([A-Z][a-z]+(?: [A-Z][a-z]+)*)` should do.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/o7zwzG/1

Answer (score 0):

You could match not a lowercase character or a newline `[^a-z\n]+` followed by matching an uppercase character `[A-Z]`.

Then capture in a group an uppercase character followed by one or more lowercase characters `[A-Z][a-z]+` followed by a repeating pattern `(?: [A-Z][a-z]+)*` that matches a whitespace and an uppercase character followed by one or more lowercase characters.

The Title Case values are in group 1.

[`[^a-z\n]+[A-Z]([A-Z][a-z]+(?: [A-Z][a-z]+)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/DRFTPZ/1)